# When does the extension of scalars to $\mathbf Q$ give the field of fractions?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $K$ be its field of fractions. Consider the ring $T=\mathbf Q\otimes_\mathbf Z R$. We have a homomorphism
$$\varphi\colon T\longrightarrow K$$
$$a\otimes r\longmapsto ar\qquad a\in \mathbf Q,r\in R.$$
Under what conditions on $R$ is $\varphi$ (a) injective, (b) surjective? When is $T$ a field? When do $T$ and $K$ coincide?

Comment: $K$ (equivalently: $R$) should be of characteristic $0$ for $\varphi$ to exist.

Comment: Any subring of the algebraic integers works. Next, is there a subring $R$ of $\mathbf Q(x)$ such that $\mathbf Q\otimes_\mathbf Z R=\mathbf Q(x)$ ? (for each $b \in \mathbf Q(x)$ add $nb$ to $R$ with $n$ chosen such that all the integers remain non inversible) Same question with $\mathbf Q(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$. If so for any field $K$ of characteristic $0$ (with countable transcendental basis over $\mathbf Q$ ?) there is a subring $R$ of $K$ such that $\mathbf Q\otimes_\mathbf Z R=K$.

Comment: If $K$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ and $R$ a subring of $K$ such that $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$, this is true.